# Memory leak issue with SwiftUI Map causing excessive memory consumption

Tags: swift, dictionary, swiftui, memory, mapkit

I'm encountering a memory leak issue in my SwiftUI app when using the Map view. Every time I navigate to the Map screen, the memory consumption spikes by approximately 120MB. I suspect there might be a problem with how I'm handling the Map view or its associated state variables.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
struct MapView: View {
    @State private var mapRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
    var viewModel: MapVM?
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Map")
                .foregroundStyle(.black)
            Map(coordinateRegion: $mapRegion, interactionModes: [.zoom, .pan])
                .frame(height: 300)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .clipped()
            // Buttons for changing the delta 
            // Buttons for dismissing the viewController via delegate.
            // viewModel.delegate.dissmissViewController()

        }
    }
}

// Root VC:
protocol HomeDelgate: AnyObject {
    func navigateForSearch()
    func navigateForMapView()
}
class HomeVC: UIViewController {
    var viewModel: HomeVM?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel?.delegate = self
        guard let viewModel else {return}
        let homeView = HomeView(viewModel: viewModel)
        
        let homeHC = UIHostingController(rootView: homeView)
        homeHC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addChild(homeHC)
        self.view.addSubview(homeHC.view)
        homeHC.didMove(toParent: self)
        homeHC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            homeHC.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            homeHC.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            homeHC.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            homeHC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    class func instantiate() -> HomeVC {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.home.instanceOf(viewController: self)!
        vc.viewModel = HomeVM()
        return vc
    }
}

extension HomeVC: HomeDelgate {
    func navigateForSearch() {
        let vc = SearchVC.instantiate()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    func navigateForPropertiesDetails() {
        let vc = MapVC.instantiate()
        self.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
// RootViewModel
class HomeVM: ObservableObject {
    weak var delegate: HomeDelgate?
    
}

// HomeView

struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: HomeVM
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ZStack {
                    Color.primary.opacity(0.05)
                    VStack {
                        HomeHeaderView(location: "A123, North Street, Southern West")
                        HomePropertisView()
                            .onTapGesture {
                // Navigation call for MapView
                                viewModel.delegate?.navigateForMapView()
                            }
                        RecommendedCardContainerView()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
            }
            .clipped()
        }
    }
}
```

Upon further investigation, I've found that each time I navigate away from the Map view, the memory isn't being released properly, leading to this gradual increase in memory consumption.

I tried to create a singleton view for map but swift is not allowing me to that.
Probably my approach was wrong.

Can anyone help me identify the source of this memory leak and provide guidance on how to fix it? Any insights or alternative approaches to handle the Map view in SwiftUI would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try with `.sheet` for MapView, and check if the memory is released or not. If the memory is released in this case, then your original MapView is just not dismissed properly, I guess.

Comment: @TaeeunKim didn't worked.

Comment: Can you include the navigation in your example?

Comment: The problem is probably the view model object, the `View` struct is a view model already so you don't need any objects for that. Try changing your `navigateForMapView` to be a closure.

Comment: didn't worked. Don't worry about the viewModel I've managed this thing already.

Comment: You are using a version of `Map(coordinateRegion: $mapRegion, interactionModes: [.zoom, .pan])` that is deprecated anyways. With iOS 17, Apple created a whole new Map API. Why do you want to stick with that old stuff?